# Which hook should be used in this case?

Tags: filters, hooks

I'm using the enter_title_here filter to modify the 'Enter title here' text in a custom post type, question is what hook should I use to trigger this function?

I have used admin_enqueue_script as a test and it worked, but I think there is a better hook since this is not really a script.

```
    function print_scripts() { 
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( 'post' === $screen->base && 'myposttype' === $screen->post_type ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', WP_CSS . 'styles.css' );
        // filter used here
        add_filter( 'enter_title_here', function() { _e("Enter name here"); } );
    }  
    }

    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'print_scripts' );
```

Comment: You just need to call the filter `enter_title_here`. No action hook is required for that. Yes, for enqueuing the script, `admin_enqueue_scripts` will do.

Comment: ok so it's all good like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was the one by @RutwickGangurde:
You just need to call the filter enter_title_here. No action hook is required for that. Yes, for enqueuing the script, admin_enqueue_scripts will do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a simple difference, here; you are echoing with *e() - try returning with _*() instead:

`function custom_title_text( $title ){
    return __( 'Enter Name here' );
}
add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'custom_title_text' );`

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself very clearly the first time round, see edited question now please. I would like to know if I'm using the correct action hook or not.

Comment: I can use the function you suggested, and then I would have to include those if statements (is there a better way to make that conditional?), and then fire that function on a hook, but which hook? admin_enqueue_scripts works, but is there a more appropriate hook for this?